# Source of SQLite Install

Tags: sqlite, homebrew, osx-yosemite

I noticed in /lib/ there's a sqlite3 folder which is fine.  But I'm not sure how it got installed.  I did not manually install it.

I did however install HomeBrew and XCode Tools, so maybe one of those also installed sqlite?  Trying to figure this out.  Just nice to know where it came from, and I doubt it's included as part of Yosemite.

Comment: Christ who the hell moved this to a -1.  Good god, give me a break!  wtf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sqlite ships with OS X (although it's stored at `/usr/lib` -- OS X doesn't have a `/lib` directory by default).